# jQuery: alternate switching of classes in several div blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 identical div blocks on the page, inside of which there are several div blocks with different texts. It looks something like this:

```
<div class="dynamic_titles">
    <div class="dynamic_title active">text 1</div>
    <div class="dynamic_title inactive">text 2</div>
    <div class="dynamic_title inactive">text 3</div>
    <div class="dynamic_title inactive">text 4</div>
    <div class="dynamic_title inactive">text 5</div>
</div>

<div class="dynamic_titles">
    <div class="dynamic_title active">text 6</div>
    <div class="dynamic_title inactive">text 7</div>
    <div class="dynamic_title inactive">text 8</div>
    <div class="dynamic_title inactive">text 9</div>
    <div class="dynamic_title inactive">text 10</div>
</div>
```

I need to change classes from `inactive` to `active` in each `dynamic_title` block in turn. That is, the next one takes `active`, and the previous one with `active` in `inactive` and so on in a circle.

When I have one `dynamic_titles` block, everything works fine, but 2 interfere with each other, break. I'm trying not to make 2 functions for each block separately, I want to make one universal one that would be applied to each block separately.

Now I have such a code, but it does not work as expected. It runs once and goes no further. If done without `.each`, it works, but again not as expected and eventually breaks. What is my mistake?

```
$('.dynamic_titles').each(function () {

    var index = 1,
        max = $(this).find('.dynamic_title').length;

    function setActiveHeadline() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(this).find('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');

            index++;
            if (index > max) {
                index = 1;
            }

            $(this).find('.dynamic_title:nth-of-type(' + index + ')').addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');

            setActiveHeadline();

        }, 3000);
    }

    setActiveHeadline();

    widthTitle = $(this).find('.dynamic_title.active').width();
    $(this).css({
        'width': widthTitle,
    });

    function setWidthHeadlines() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            widthTitle = $(this).find('.dynamic_title.active').width();

            $(this).css({
                'width': widthTitle,
            });

            setWidthHeadlines();

        }, 3000);
    }
    setWidthHeadlines();
})
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could simplify this into one function that uses `setInterval`, please see the following snippet:

```js
$(function(){
    //use setInterval to continue the changes
    setInterval(() => {
        //iterate the blocks
        $('div.dynamic_titles').each(function() {
            //get the children
            const $children = $(this).find('div.dynamic_title');
            //get the number of children
            const numofchildren = $children.length;
            //index for switching active in children
            let activeindex = 0;
            //iterate children to find the active one
            $children.each(function(i, el) {
                 //if active, remove active and add inactive classNames
                 //store the index
                 //break the each loop
                 if($(el).hasClass('active')){
                    $(el).removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
                    activeindex = i + 1;
                    return false;
                 }
            });
            
            //if index has reached the last child, reset to zero
            if(activeindex > numofchildren - 1){
               activeindex = 0;
            }
            //set the next child to active and remove inactive className
            $children[activeindex].classList.add('active');
            $children[activeindex].classList.remove('inactive');
        });
    }, 3000);
})
```

```css
.active {
   color:green;
}

.inactive {
   color:grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="dynamic_titles">
    <div class="dynamic_title active">text 1</div>
    <div class="dynamic_title inactive">text 2</div>
    <div class="dynamic_title inactive">text 3</div>
    <div class="dynamic_title inactive">text 4</div>
    <div class="dynamic_title inactive">text 5</div>
</div>

<div class="dynamic_titles">
    <div class="dynamic_title active">text 6</div>
    <div class="dynamic_title inactive">text 7</div>
    <div class="dynamic_title inactive">text 8</div>
    <div class="dynamic_title inactive">text 9</div>
    <div class="dynamic_title inactive">text 10</div>
</div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-3zlB5s2uwoUzrXK3BT7AX3FyvojsraNFxCc2vC/7pNI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```